# Can we have team wise burndown and kanban board on VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

We have started working on an Azure DevOps project. As the team is getting bigger, we want to have multiple teams.

Can we have team wise burndown and kanban board on Azure DevOps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Make [additional teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/add-teams?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav) and assign them an area path. Each team gets its own backlog, Kanban boards, dashboards, etc.